# Selecting the proper HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I use Nightwatch.js to test foreign website code. I used this command:

```
.waitForElementVisible('input[id="inputField"]', TIMEOUT)
```

This should wait until the specified element is visible. But I get this warning:

> Warn: WaitForElement found 24 elements for selector "input[id="inputField"]". Only the first one will be checked.

I thought the id of a tag is unique. How is it possible to get a list of 24 elements when looking for this id?
What can I do now to select exactly the element I need?

Comment: *"How is it possible to get a list of 24 elements when looking for this id?"* Because people constantly fail to understand the basic concept that `id`s must be unique. Apparently, the site you're testing against was written by one or more of those people.

Comment: Just because it is meant to be unique does not mean it really is. The browser will not crash nor deny wrongly multiplied ids.

Comment: you'll need to select with another selector.If you know the particular input in DOM.You can then select the nth-child selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could now solve the problem by selecting an unambiguous parent element and then selected the child of the child of it; something like this:

```
div[id="listItem_0"] > span > input[id="inputField"]
```

Answer (score 4):

> How is it possible to get a list of 24 elements when looking for this id?

Because people constantly fail to understand the basic concept that `id`s must be unique. Apparently, the site you're testing against was written by one or more of those people.

> What can I do now to select exactly the element I need?

According to the documentation, Nightwatch.js lets you use XPath as an alternative to CSS. With XPath, you can specify which of a set of elements to target, e.g.:

```
.useXpath()
.waitForElementVisible('//input[@id="inputField"][1]', TIMEOUT)
```

...would use the first, `[2]` would use the second, etc.

If you can't do it by the index of the element in the document, you'll need to find other things about it you can use to select it (with CSS or XPath).

Comment: I think the second part of the question referes to how to find out which of those 24 results is the one looked for - which like this, seems not possible.

Comment: @JavaScript: I don't understand what you mean by "is the one looked for."

Comment: Well let's assume we are looking for one specific element -  which has this id and contains a code block we wish to analyse. Yet we retrieved 24. How do I get the one which contains the code block I wanted to analyse in the first place. Yet that is just how I comprehended the question.

Comment: the xpath selector somehow does not work. however i could now solve the problem by selecting an unambiguous parent element and then selected the child of the child of it; something like this: `div[id="listItem_0"] > span > input[id="inputField"]`

Comment: @Garrarufa: Yeah, that's what I was talking about with the last line of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The id of an element *should* be unique. However that doesn't take out the ability for a developer to create as many elements with the same id on the page as he wants.

Also, id selectors are usually specified like this `input#inputField`.